# How to secure a private key used by a web server to decrypt string store in a db?

Tags: encryption-asymmetric

I'm developing a small app that will help users easily get information from their isp provider, by scrapping their isp account page.  For that to be possible I need their username and password store in my db.  To keep their password safe I will use an openssl public key to encode it in my db and a private key to decode it before my scraper logs in to their account page.

I'm wondering where to put my private key so the passwords are safe even if someone take controller of my web server?  Because It would be totally inappropriate to just leave the private key on the web server...

tks

Answer (score 0):

If someone takes total control of your server and is interested in those passwords, he will succeed. Always take this into consideration and make plans on what to do in this case.

Now to make it as hard as possible and improbable to achieve this, I suggest to store the key (or better, the passwords) in some kind of memory table: like a Ramdisk, a script that will give out only one password per minute and delete itself if called more than that etc.

I don't see any positive effect of using public key encryption here, the key to decrypt must be stored on the server no matter what you use. You may look for Howtos that descripe the problem of https-certificates, they should be protected by passphrases and must be read on server start - the problem is related.

Probably a good solution would be to log into the server, store the passwordfile in a ramdisk and log out. Repeat on Server reboot, crash or password change.